# How can I handle two versions of a project?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have two versions of a project that have some minor differences to each other. Also the base of the project (common part) is changing frequently. To handle this situation I am using `git` and `TortoiseGit`.
For example `br1`(1st version) and `br2`(2nd version) are sub-branches of master.

```
master
  |----br1
  |----br2
```

Now When I'm working on branch `br1` I want to commit **some** changes to `master` branch. Is it possible? Or do you have any other suggestion to handle this situation?

Comment: Are you looking for [`git cherry-pick`](http://technosophos.com/2009/12/04/git-cherry-picking-move-small-code-patches-across-branches.html)?

Comment: @larsmans: It's very useful, Is there any solution in tortoisegit?

Comment: If you're using two branches for this, you're using Git the wrong way, because you'll want branches to receive the same patches again and again (as long as they concern the base part). Use a single branch, and another way to make different versions of your project (it depends on where the differences fit)

Comment: Tortoise Git also allow Cherry Pick. Don't remember how, but you can also do it using `gitk --all` (it's in the contextual menu).

Comment: Cherry picking is possible in TortoiseGit by opening the log, switching to master branch, selecting the commits you want to cherry-pick and then choosing "Cherry pick selected commits" on the context menu

Answer (score 1):

Also you can create 3rd branch like "common". It will be harder to switch between branches to make common/branch specific changes but it will be easier to merge it.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution is this:

while on master use this command:

git cherry-pick

Where the  is the hash of the commit you want to put on the master (from br1 or br2).

However, you need to be careful with this workflow: as time goes by, master, br1 and br2 will begin to diverge more and more, therefore the files holding the differences will become larger and the repo slower.